# iPad css design - can't hide overflow

Tags: css, ipad, overflow, media-queries

I have a website with multiple divs that are hidden off the page (they slide on using jquery functions when called). I'm now styling the site for ipads and the 'overflow:hidden' command doesn't seem to be working. You can scroll the page to the left and right and up and down to reveal all the divs that should be hidden.

Is there a reason this command doesn't work, and how can I work around it so that my page overflow is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hiding them off the edge of the page you could hide them with css using:

`display:none;` and `display:block;` or

`visibility:hidden;` and `visibility:visible;`

or if you would like to fade them in you could use: `opacity:0;` and `opacity:1;`

or you could use jQuery:
`.fadeIn();` and `.fadeOut();`

Long story short, I would place your hidden divs at the edge of the page, hidden with one of the above methods, and then simultaneously reveal it and move it in to place.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, need to see code for better answer.